# Inital load view controller will not response to web view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, webview

I have two view controller one is informationViewController and another InformationDetailedViewController.   there are two button on button action i am loading respective url pdf files

```
// InformationViewController.m
       // About Us button clicked
        -(void)aboutUsAction:(id)sender{
            [informationDetailedViewController showInformation:0];
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:informationDetailedViewController animated:YES];
        }

        // Terms and condition button clicked
        -(void)termsAndConditionAction:(id)sender{
            [informationDetailedViewController showInformation:1];
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:informationDetailedViewController animated:YES];
        }

  // InformationDetailedViewController.m    
    - (void)viewDidLoad{

        [super viewDidLoad];    
        // create a webview
        webInfoDetailed = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
        webInfoDetailed.scalesPageToFit = YES;
        [webInfoDetailed setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        [self.view addSubview:webInfoDetailed];    
    }

    -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
        [super viewWillAppear:YES];
    }


    -(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
        [super viewDidAppear:YES];
    }

        // InInformationDetailedViewController.1
        -(void)showInformation:(int )informationId {

            NSString *informationType = @"";
            switch (informationId) {
                case 0:
                    self.title = @"About Us";
                    informationType = KHABOUTUS;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    self.title = @"Disclaimer";

                    informationType = KHDISCLAIMER;
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }

            NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL URLWithString:informationType];
            NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:targetURL];
            [webInfoDetailed loadRequest:request];
        }
```

The issue is on initial load (first time load ) url is not loading on webView. 
When click back and then click AboutUs or Terms and Condition its working perfectly. Its very small thing i am missing here.
@All Thanks In Advance

Comment: It is not working because the web view is not loaded when you are calling showInformation:0. You are pushing it after this statement. Then the webview is loaded. So to fix this. You pass an integer to the detail view. And from the detail view you should call the function showInformation:x.  x is the integer property. Let me know if you need code for this.

Comment: @Jassi thanks for your input!!! its fixed   -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:YES];
    NSLog(@"value in typeID %d",typeID);
    [self showInformation:typeID];

}

Answer (score 1):

Expanding Jassi's comment, here is a code snippet that may help you.

In

> InformationDetailedViewController.h

```
@property int informationId; // make it as a member of VC.
```

Change showInformation method such that it uses the informationId member instead of parameter in

> In InformationDetailedViewController.m

```
-(void)showInformation { //you can omit the parameter, and do not forget to change the declaration in header file
  NSString *informationType = @"";
  switch (self.informationId) {
    case 0:
      self.title = @"About Us";
      informationType = KHABOUTUS;
    break;
    case 1:
      self.title = @"Disclaimer";
      informationType = KHDISCLAIMER;
    break;
    default:
    break;
  }

  NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL URLWithString:informationType];
  NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:targetURL];
  [webInfoDetailed loadRequest:request];
}
```

Finally, replace the call for showInformation method in

> InformationViewController.m

```
        // About Us button clicked
        -(void)aboutUsAction:(id)sender{
            [informationDetailedViewController setInformationId:0];
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:informationDetailedViewController animated:YES];
        }

        // Terms and condition button clicked
        -(void)termsAndConditionAction:(id)sender{
            [informationDetailedViewController setInformationId:1];
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:informationDetailedViewController animated:YES];
        }
```

Hope it helps.